# Monotonic properties of rotations

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

Let $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$, and let $\theta_j$ a sequence such that $\forall j \; \theta_j \in [0,2\pi]$, $\theta_j \to \theta$ with the property

$$
|\theta_j - \theta| \geq |\theta_{j+1} - \theta|.
$$

Let $R_{\psi}$ the rotation matrix, counter clockwise, respect to $\psi$. By drawing something on paper I can see that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ I have

$$
\lVert \left(R_{\theta_j - \theta} - I\right)x \rVert_2 \geq \lVert \left(R_{\theta_{j+1} - \theta} - I\right)x \rVert_2
$$

But how can I prove this formally?

My attempt were probably too convoluted, mainly based on matrix norms to derive bounds, but I haven't actually got anything yet. Even a clue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Those norms are equal to $2\left\|x\right\|\sin(\alpha/2)$ (for the corresponding angle $\alpha$) using just plane trigonometry in the plane span by $x$ and its rotation.

Comment: I can't really see why

Comment: $0$, $x$ and $Rx$ form a isosceles triangle with base the segment from $x$ to $Rx$ and angle at $0$ equal to $\alpha$, the angle of rotation. Draw the perpendicular from $0$ to the base and compute half the base using trigonometry on one of the right angle triangle that got formed. That is the $\left\|x\right\|\sin(\alpha/2)$. The whole base is twice of that.

Comment: @Hellen I'll have a look to that later, can this allow me to show my result then? And out of curiosity do you think it is possible to derive the same result using linear algebra tools? (like dot product, cauchy schwartz, etc)

Comment: It can help you show that your result is false. For example if $\theta=0$, $\theta_{j+1}-\theta=\pi$ and $\theta_i-\theta=2\pi-0.00000001$ then $\sin((\theta_{j+1}-\theta)/2)=1$ but $\sin((\theta_i-\theta)/2)$ is almost zero. It is almost true, though. With a little care on the condition that you want to impose on the angles. It is eventually true, too.